# Why is Werner Heisenberg smiling?

Tags: history

This is not a joke. It is something I have wondered about for a long time.  Nearly every picture of Werner Heisenberg shows him smiling.

[image: Heisenberg is happy]
[image: Heisenberg is still happy]
[image: Even in old age, Heisenberg is still smiling]

This is unusual.  The difference between Heisenberg and other physicists is striking. Try an image search for Dirac or Schrödinger and you will see a lot of scowling, sour faces. It is possible that Niels Bohr smiled once but if so there does not seem to be any photographic evidence.

Was Heisenberg noted for being a particularly cheerful guy?

Comment: Maybe because he  understood faulty [sampling](http://www.aif.it/FISICI/F49_1b.jpg).

Comment: I did historical research on this and found out something about it. I would have posted a substantive answer here, but the question was closed. Too bad!

Comment: Perhaps a blessing in disguise. The one time I actually saw him in person, he was grim as an undertaker at a yoga class.